# How to insert TIMESTAMP-format value from excel into database

Tags: php, mysql, excel, timestamp

I want to insert TIMESTAMP-format value from excel into database. The value is somewhat like this "1/6/2016  12:00:00 AM". I use this code to insert the value into database

```
$TimeStamp = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A' . $row)->getValue()));
```

but the value turns out like this "42522". Its seems that the value is transferred incorrectly. It seems that the code is faulty and is not suitable for use of insertion of a TimeStamp-format value. May I know how to correct this ?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the column type in the DB table?

Comment: I named it as Timestamp and declare as varchar(25)

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores dates internally as number of days since January 1, 1900. 
For example: "June 9th, 2011 10:30 AM" would be stored as "40703.4375".
40703 is the number of full days since 01/01/1900 and 0.4375 represents the time (10.5/24 = 0.4375).

When you process dates read from an Excel spreadsheet (e.g. using PHPExcel) you often want to convert them into a UNIX timestamp i.e. a number of seconds elapsed since midnight of January 1, 1970 UTC.

Here is a PHP code to do that:

```
    // Numbers of days between January 1, 1900 and 1970 (including 19 leap years) 
define("MIN_DATES_DIFF", 25569); 

// Numbers of second in a day: 
define("SEC_IN_DAY", 86400);    

function excel2timestamp($excelDate) 
{ 
   if ($excelDate <= MIN_DATES_DIFF) 
      return 0; 

   return  ($excelDate - MIN_DATES_DIFF) * SEC_IN_DAY; 
}
```

If you provide the Excel spreadsheet that you later on read from in your app you could add a hidden cell that would calculate the timestamp for you, within the spreadsheet. 
Assuming that B2 is the cell that stores your date the formula for calculating timestamp would be:

Code:
=(B2-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400
Now you only need to read the calculated value from the hidden cell.

Comment: I used this '$DateTime2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($DateTime));
        $DateTime2 = excel2timestamp($DateTime2);  ' code but return 0. May I know why ?

Comment: The excel cannot be edited because it is from a third party. Editing is not possible. May I know how to implement this inside the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Excel is giving you right information and you are also doing it correctly.  To clarify, Excel Stores Time Stamp Value in Integer Format. So, here you are getting value "42552" Which is obviously right, now you have to use this function to Achieve what you are doing

```
<?php
function ExcelToTimeStamp($dateValue = 0, $ExcelBaseDate=0) {
    if ($ExcelBaseDate == 0) {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 25569;
        //  Adjust for the spurious 29-Feb-1900 (Day 60)
        if ($dateValue < 60) {
            --$myExcelBaseDate;
        }
    } else {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 24107;
    }

    // Perform conversion
    if ($dateValue >= 1) {
        $utcDays = $dateValue - $myExcelBaseDate;
        $returnValue = round($utcDays * 86400);
        if (($returnValue <= PHP_INT_MAX) && ($returnValue >= -PHP_INT_MAX)) {
            $returnValue = (integer) $returnValue;
        }
    } else {
        $hours = round($dateValue * 24);
        $mins = round($dateValue * 1440) - round($hours * 60);
        $secs = round($dateValue * 86400) - round($hours * 3600) - round($mins * 60);
        $returnValue = (integer) gmmktime($hours, $mins, $secs);
    }

    // Return
    return $returnValue;
}
$myTimestamp =  // Output will be 146473920001 and it is a timestamp in php you can store it

echo date('d M Y', $myTimestamp); now convert that timestamp value in any format you want usnig date()
?>
```